# Insert into SQL database only if does not exist

Tags: sql-server, excel, vba

Using VBA to insert into microsoft sql database

```
SELECT ALL *
FROM [MarketAnalysis].[dbo].[ReviewDatabase]
WHERE [VESSEL] = 'BOATY'
  AND [LOAD DATE] BETWEEN DATEADD(day, -3,'20190227') AND DATEADD(day, +3,'20190227')
ORDER BY [ID] DESC
```

for example, the above, if insert a vessel that matches the name and date +/- 3 days, let it not as it matches something already in the DB

Comment: @Larnu `ALL *` is valid T-SQL syntax, although usually redundant

Comment: That between statement may not be doing quite what you think. If the datatype of your day column is a datetime it will not return any rows that on the +3 days because the timestamp would be greater than the beginning of the day. When it comes to date calculations (and many more things) between can really be problematic. https://sqlblog.org/2011/10/19/what-do-between-and-the-devil-have-in-common

Answer (score 0):

Use `IF NOT EXISTS` and remove the `ORDER BY`

```
IF NOT EXISTS(SELECT *
FROM [MarketAnalysis].[dbo].[ReviewDatabase]
  WHERE [VESSEL] = 'BOATY'
  AND [LOAD DATE] BETWEEN DATEADD(day, -3,'20190227') AND DATEADD(day, +3,'20190227'))
BEGIN
--your insert statement
END
```

Comment: Fantastic, is there a way to get a response if it does exist? i.e. Msgbox "this is already in the database"

Comment: This is being answered in a follow up question from the OP [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55028025/return-if-a-success-vba-sql)